# CMake .. produces output in parent directory

Tags: cmake, boringssl

I'm trying to build [BoringSSL by Google](http://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/). The BUILDING file instructions clearly indicate that the output should go under the build directory.

I have a directory `project`, and under it I've created `build`. There is a CMakeLists.txt file under `project`, and I would like it to build inside the `build` directory. However, when I run `cmake ..` from inside `build`, the makefile is produced in the `project` directory instead of the current `build` directory.

Most instructions I found seem to indicate that the output of cmake goes into the current directory, regardless of where CMakeLists.txt is located. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: You'll probably need to show us the CMakeLists.txt you're using.

Comment: Specifically, I'm trying to build boringssl by google. The BUILDING file instructions clearly indicate that the output should go under the build directory: https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that since I ran cmake in the top level `project` directory, running it again from inside `build` didn't produce a new output. Removing CMakeCache.txt from `project` should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I made the following files/directory:

```
.
`-- project
    |-- build
    `-- CMakeLists.txt
```

With CMakeLists.txt content:

```
PROJECT(TEST)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
```

Then I went into the ./project/build folder and ran `cmake ..`

```
[~/project/build] cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is Intel 13.1.0.20130313
-- The CXX compiler identification is Intel 13.1.0.20130313
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/icc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/icc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/icpc
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/icpc -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: ~/project/build
```

And all the generated files were in the `./project/build` folder.

Try opening up your CMakeCache.txt file (it should be generated in the directory you ran CMake from) and check out variables like TEST_BINARY_DIR and CMAKE_CACHEFILE_DIR. They should set to your build directory for example.